# Protobuf serialization/deserialization fails

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

With nested messages protobuf serialization and then deserialization fails due to default recursion limit. While this can be fixed by using 'SetRecursionLimit', However  If these protobuf's are used along with GRPC service interface, how does one can optimize the fix (without extra copy, much no/less code)

For example, Proto as below

```
message MyMsg {
     oneof req {
        string name=1;
        int64  id=2;
        MyMsg msg=3;
    }
  }

MyMsg pbMsg;
.../* Fill up pbMsg */
std::string str;
pbMsg.SerializeToString(&str);
```

To rebuild pb from the string, This fails due to nested recursion in the pb msg

```
MyMsg decodedMsg;
decodedMsg.ParseFromString(str);  // fails due to nested recursion
```

However to rebuild pb from the string, I need to do following

```
 google::protobuf::io::ArrayInputStream raw(str.data(), str.size());
 google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream input(&raw);
 input.SetRecursionLimit(xxx); //any number larger than default 100 depending on recursion
 decodedMsg.ParseFromCodedStream(&input);
```

Now this works and decodedMsg(output) and pbMsg(input) is same.

1. Is there better way to fix this problem, except avoiding the nested messages ?
2. If the PB is using  from gRPC service, then it means extra operation on PB at client at every response, is there any better way of dealing with it ?