# GRPC access response byte-buffer

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, rpc

In continuation of [Protobuf serialization/deserialization fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76950591/protobuf-serialization-deserialization-fails) (On protobuf issue)
I have GRPC service where response could be deep-recursion (Nested).

```
syntax = "proto3";
service RecursionTest {
    rpc GetMeRecursiveProto(Req) returns (Response) {}
}
message Req {
    int64 level=1;
}
message msg {
    string name=1;
}
message final {
    msg first=1;
    int64 level=2;
    repeated final inner=3;
}
message Response {
    final resp = 1;
}
```

Client send, requested level for recursion, and server respond back with nested-pb. However for nest-ed message more than 100 level, grpc fails. Is there way to access byte-buffer of response and build the protobuf response from coded stream with answer given in [Protobuf serialization/deserialization fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76950591/protobuf-serialization-deserialization-fails)

```
    grpc::Status status = stub->GetMeRecursiveProto(&context, request, &response);
```

rpc failure error code and error string
" 12, No message returned for unary request"

Answer (score 1):

FYI - support for increasing the recursion limit in grpc-java was recently added in [#10043](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/pull/10094/files). The change discussed in more detail in [#9643](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/9643).

The change was released in [v1.56.0](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/releases/tag/v1.56.0)

Comment: Thanks for response. I am looking for c++/golang and running v1.51